# No texture in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

No texture showing in cycles render. Good in cycles. Here the picture of problem:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, because cycles is a bit different to add a texture you should do this - first  click on use nodes in the materials tab. Then click on the dot next to color and then select "image texture". Now click on the drop down menu below the "image texture" on the left, it should have your img file.Cycles by default uses uv's so it should look fine